# Hibernate search - match null date field

Tags: hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I want to implement a query to get entities where endDate is null, for this i use indexNullAs because null values are not indexed

```
@Field(analyze = Analyze.NO, indexNullAs = Field.DEFAULT_NULL_TOKEN)
@DateBridge(resolution = Resolution.DAY)
private Date endDate;
```

but i have the below error

> HSEARCH000325: The 'indexNullAs' property for field 'endDate', with
> value '*null*', has invalid format: HSEARCH000293: The 'indexNullAs'
> property for fields indexed as Longs must represent a Long number.
> Could not parse '*null*'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much what the error says. Internally, dates are indexed as `long` numbers, so your null token must be a `long` too.

Just pick a `long` value that will not conflict with the representation of valid dates, for example `9223372036854775807` (the maximum `long` value).

Alternatively, if your project is not too large (yet), you can also migrate to [Hibernate Search 6](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/reference/en-US/html_single/) (in beta, but well tested and approaching the final release). Among many improvements, Hibernate Search 6 has an [`exists` predicate](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-dsl-predicate-exists), making the "null token" unnecessary.